# Swing Java- I want add Apples and Oranges to basket with Jbuttons and print it out

Tags: java, swing

For my project i have to be able to add For eg. Apples to A Basket using Swing i would like to use JButtons For that is there a way of doing that or is there another alternative to my question.

Here is a bit of my code.

```
Apple.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
            {
            //  System.out.println("" + text.getText());
            AppleButton.setVisible(true);
            OrangeButton.setVisible(true);
            BasketButton.setVisible(true);
            InfoButton.setVisible(true);

            }
        });
```

I Want to add AppleButton to BasketButton and then print out the information for e.g "Apple Has been Added to a Basket" and then if i press orangeButton It will print out the info about apple and underneath it "Orange has been added to a basket".

Comment: Maybe you should have a look at [How to use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) and maybe consider using a [`JToggleButton`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html)

Comment: You shall read a good material on Swing first. There are lots of available on web.